# Is there an alternative to "Create or replace procedure" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Is there an version of "create or replace procedure" for MySQL? I can't seem to do this or script the dropping of the procedure if exists before recompiling without getting an error message that the stored procedure exists.

```
DELIMITER $$

-- would love to be able to drop procedure if exists db.sp_tmp_90days;  
-- or use "create or replace"

create procedure db.sp_tmp_90days()

BEGIN
drop table db.tmp_90days;

create table db.tmp_90days ( 
    user_name varchar(128), 
    first_name varchar(50), 
    last_name varchar(50), 
    system varchar(10), 
    last_login datetime 
);

alter table db.tmp_90days add index idx_user_name(user_name);
alter table db.tmp_90days add index idx_system(system);
alter table db.tmp_90days add index idx_last_login(last_login);

insert into db.tmp_90days (user_name, first_name, last_name, system, last_login)
    SELECT
        [...]
END $$
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is the syntax to drop it if it exists

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS db.sp_tmp_90days;
```

Comment: Could also mention that MariaDB, a "drop-in replacement" for MySQL, does support the `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE` syntax since version 10.1.

Comment: @dbdemon thanks that's helpful!

Comment: can we use create or replace with `definer`?

Comment: FYI, I rejected [this edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/192908) since SQL syntax highlighting is automatically active for most questions - tags may automatically apply it; check the bottom of [this page](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/mysql/info).

Comment: @Glorfindel, I was not sure if it was.  I waited for it to colour up and it didn't, thats when I applied the edit.